# how to install wifi driver in acer aspire es1-522

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, acer, atheros

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in Acer Aspire ES1-522 alongside Windows 10.
Wifi works fine in Windows 10, but it is not working in Ubuntu. The output of 
`lspci -k | grep -i wireless` is :

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
```

It doesn't show any wifi network. I dont know is it true or not but it shows wifi network while i connect it to charging

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though its weird, but i am going to answer my own question.

You don't need to install/remove any driver. Just goto /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf open this file with root privileges and add line

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

to the end of file. reboot and enjoy

Comment: I would suggest creating a separate file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf`. It this case it will not be overwritten on updates and it will be easier to find why the module does not start.